# Return multiple values from function

Tags: function, return, dart

Is there a way to return several values in a function return statement (other than returning an object) like we can do in Go (or some other languages)?

For example, in Go we can do:

```
func vals() (int, int) {
    return 3, 7
}
```

Can this be done in Dart?  Something like this:

```
int, String foo() {
    return 42, "foobar";
}
```

Comment: I don't know if any languages truly return multiple values. Python, which uses the same syntax as you used above, returns a tuple, which is just a simple object. I suspect Go is similar.

Comment: Relevant: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!topic/misc/j-1I--HjXag

Comment: Lua can also return multiple values.

Comment: These now exist in Dart 3.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76257744/1759443

Answer (score 182, accepted):

**Updated for Dart 3.0**

In Dart 3.0 records can be used

- https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-3-53f065a10635
- https://dart.dev/language/records

```dart
(int, String) foo() {
    return (42, "foobar");
} 

void main() {
  var (a,b) = foo();
  print("int: ${a}");
  print("String: ${b}");
}
```

**Original answer**

Dart doesn't support multiple return values.

You can return an array,

```
List foo() {
  return [42, "foobar"];
}
```

or if you want the values be typed use a `Tuple` class like the package https://pub.dev/packages/tuple provides.

See also [`either`](https://pub.dev/packages/either) for a way to return a value or an error.

Comment: +1 for `tuple` which does most closely what Go does with its built-in. It's just not built into Dart, presumably not much needed yet and they keep the language as light as possible.

Comment: There were other priorities. Features like this were discussed several times. Currently it's about Dart 2.0 with strong mode and generic functions and a lot of preparation for faster iteration after 2.0 (unified front end, kernel). Next hopefully non-nullable types and others. I prefer to not add too many features, but I have full trust in the Dart team to make the right decisions.

Comment: Also *either* is dart 2.0 **INCOMPATIBLE**.

Comment: Change the return type to `List<dynamic>` or `List<Object>`

Comment: @zypro For a Dart 2.0 compatible `Either` implementation, see [`dartz`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz).

Comment: This answer is no longer true now that Dart 3 has records.

Answer (score 27):

I'd like to add that one of the main use-cases for multiple return values in Go is error handling which Dart handle's in its own way with Exceptions and failed promises.

Of course this leaves a few other use-cases, so let's see how code looks when using explicit tuples:

```dart
import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';

Tuple2<int, String> demo() {
  return new Tuple2(42, "life is good");
}

void main() {
  final result = demo();
  if (result.item1 > 20) {
    print(result.item2);
  }
}
```

Not quite as concise, but it's clean and expressive code. What I like most about it is that it doesn't need to change much once your quick experimental project really takes off and you start adding features and need to add more structure to keep on top of things.

```dart
class FormatResult {
  bool changed;
  String result;
  FormatResult(this.changed, this.result);
}

FormatResult powerFormatter(String text) {
  bool changed = false;
  String result = text;
  // secret implementation magic
  // ...
  return new FormatResult(changed, result);
}

void main() {
  String draftCode = "print('Hello World.');";
  final reformatted = powerFormatter(draftCode);
  if (reformatted.changed) {
    // some expensive operation involving servers in the cloud.
  }
}
```

So, yes, it's not much of an improvement over Java, but it works, it is clear, and reasonably efficient for building UIs. And I really like how I can quickly hack things together (sometimes starting on DartPad in a break at work) and then add structure later when I know that the project will live on and grow.

Comment: A common patter from functional programming for that use case is https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/either

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel, let's use a package, because next thing is that someone wants a 3 element tuple, then there's Tuple3, and so on...

Answer (score 18):

Create a class:

```
import 'dart:core';

class Tuple<T1, T2> {
  final T1 item1;
  final T2 item2;

  Tuple({
    required this.item1,
    required this.item2,
  });

  factory Tuple.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Tuple(
      item1: json['item1'],
      item2: json['item2'],
    );
  }
}
```

Call it however you want!

```
Tuple<double, double>(item1: i1,item2: i2);
or
Tuple<double, double>.fromJson(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a class to return multiple values
Ej:

```
class NewClass {
  final int number;
  final String text;

  NewClass(this.number, this.text);
}
```

Function that generates the values:

```
 NewClass buildValues() {
        return NewClass(42, 'foobar');
      }
```

Print:

```
void printValues() {
    print('${this.buildValues().number} ${this.buildValues().text}');
    // 42 foobar
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Dart is finalizing [records](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/records/records-feature-specification.md), a fancier tuple essentially.
Should be in a stable release with Dart 3.
It's already available with [experiments flags](https://dart.dev/tools/experiment-flags).

Comment: A month, you say?

Comment: @claudekennilol Seems executives pushed it back for Google IO which was a couple days ago so it's now available on stable. Making a package with examples soon. Might see this pattern with macros too.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have noted, Dart 3.0 adds [records](https://dart.dev/language/records), which can be used to return multiple values in a type-safe way.

For earlier versions of Dart, the *proper* way to return multiple values would be to store those values in a class, whether your own custom class or a [`Tuple`](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple).  However, defining a separate class for every function is very inconvenient, and using `Tuple`s can be error-prone since the members won't have meaningful names.

Another (admittedly gross and not very Dart-istic) approach is try to mimic the output-parameter approach typically used by C and C++.  For example:

```dart
class OutputParameter<T> {
  T value;

  OutputParameter(this.value);
}

void foo(
  OutputParameter<int> intOut,
  OutputParameter<String>? optionalStringOut,
) {
  intOut.value = 42;
  optionalStringOut?.value = 'foobar';
}

void main() {
  var theInt = OutputParameter(0);
  var theString = OutputParameter('');
  foo(theInt, theString);
  print(theInt.value); // Prints: 42
  print(theString.value); // Prints: foobar
}
```

It certainly can be a bit inconvenient for callers to have to use `variable.value` everywhere, but in some cases it might be worth the trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Set<Object>` for returning multiple values,

```
Set<object> foo() {
     return {'my string',0}
}

print(foo().first) //prints 'my string'

print(foo().last) //prints 0
```

Comment: I don't think Sets are ordered so using first/last is incorrect imho

Comment: sets are ordered as I believe , so you will get the items in the order that you return

Comment: Apparently, the default Set is indeed ordered (see https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.6/dart-core/Set-class.html).  Note however that not all Sets are ordered in Dart.  (unfortunately, I can't remove my downvote)

Answer (score 0):

you  can use dartz package for Returning multiple data types

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yMXUC4W1cc&t=110s

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should provide enough detail to answer the question on their own. External links should only be used to provide supplemental information or used as a citation to your answer.

Comment: Instead of providing a video you can provide enough detail answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in Dart 3.0 (Flutter 3.10.0). They are called ["Records" (full doc here)](https://dart.dev/language/records).

Here are some of my favorite examples:

Return types

```dart
(int x, double y) geoLocation(String name) =>
    return (-1, 36.8219);
```

Accessing them:

```dart
var record = ('first', a: 2, b: true, 'last');

print(record.$1); // Prints 'first'
print(record.a); // Prints 2
print(record.b); // Prints true
print(record.$2); // Prints 'last'
```

Variables

```dart
// Record type annotation in a variable declaration:
(String, int) record;

// Initialize it with a record expression:
record = ('A string', 123);
```

Named args!

```dart
// Record type annotation in a variable declaration:
({int a, bool b}) record;

// Initialize it with a record expression:
record = (a: 123, b: true);
```

Answer (score -1):

In this type of situation in Dart, an easy solution could return a list then accessing the returned list as per your requirement. You can access the specific value by the index or the whole list by a simple for loop.

```
List func() {
  return [false, 30, "Ashraful"];
}

void main() {
  final list = func();
  
  // to access specific list item
  var item = list[2];
  
  // to check runtime type
  print(item.runtimeType);
  
  // to access the whole list
  for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    print(list[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format