# Returning two integers in the same function

Tags: flutter, dart

I created the following function to return two random integer values:

```
List<int> randomGenerator() {
  return [(Random().nextInt(6) + 1),(Random().nextInt(6) + 1)];
}
```

And want to set to two program variables (left and right dice).

So tried by executing:

```
[rightDiceNumber,leftDiceNumber] = randomGenerator();
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your return value like this

```
List randomValues;
randomValues=randomGenerator();
print(randomValues[0]);
print(randomValues[1]);
```

Comment: I have already two variables: `rightDiceNumber` and `leftDiceNumber` and want to save into them. Without having to create an intermediate list. Is it possible?

Comment: No brother, it's not possible in dart. you can use list to get multiple return values. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328618/6263015