# List of tuples in flutter/dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I would like to have a list of tuples in dart/flutter, loop over them and read the first and second variable. There is a [pub.dev package](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple) that creates a tuple in flutter.
Is there another way in dart? Do I need to use a class to create a tuple like the flutter package does?

I began to create an example in [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
void main() {
  List testList = [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3),("d",4),("e",5)];
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('hello $i');
    currentItem = testList[i];

  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot install/use pub.dev packages in dartpad. Try them in your local sdk installation.

Comment: The question was more generally, wether one can do it without this package. And how it would look in flutter. This is not a question about dartpad

Comment: Why does it have to be a "tuple"? What's wrong with a `List`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You'll have to use this package. See this for more insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326310/return-multiple-values-from-function

Comment: @happy_san I don't see why it's a *requirement* to use this package. What's the issue with a `List` as your linked question suggests?

Comment: @Christopher Moore It does not have to be tuple class and it should not be. The testList at is it defined above is ill-defined and I would like to know the the correct form if existent.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider What do you mean "correct form"? Again, what's wrong with just using a `List`?

Comment: @happy_san Thanks for the answer, but the question in your post is slightly different. Maybe it is impossible to return multiple values but possible to have a list with each item being a tuple.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider Can you address my previous comments?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider Could you explain your use case?

Comment: @ Christopher Moore Sure, sorry for the delay. I need to loop over a list of two values. Either I take two lists and zip them together. Or I create one list of tuple objects, or list objects of two elements. I would prefer the second option with tuples because it could easily take Python outputs.

Comment: @ happy_san I would like to index a list of tuples where the first entry is a path to an image (String) and the second is the class it belongs to (Int).

Comment: Considered using a `Map` for this data structure?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider What's wrong with a `List`? There is no "correct form", it's just whatever works for you.

Comment: @ julemand101 Yes, but I assume, the problem with a tuple stays the same. Actually, I just need to understand how to create a map/list element, whose entries are either tuples or lists of two values, (or another map with two entries.)

Comment: @ Christopher Moore There is no problem with a list, but the current way of the testList - in the Python form - throws errors. So I would like to have the "corrected form" of my attempt in the example.

Comment: There is no such thing as a tuple in native Dart. Either use the external tuple package or use another data structure like `List` or `Map`. That's pretty much the long and short of it.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore A `List` is a collection of elements with a homogeneous type (which would end up being `Object` if the elements aren't the same type).  A tuple is a collection of elements with heterogeneous types.  A `Map` could be a substitute if there are only two elements.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Example of how you can iterate over your data pairs by using a `Map` as data structure:

```
void main() {
  final testMap = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5};

  for (final mapEntry in testMap.entries) {
    final key = mapEntry.key;
    final value = mapEntry.value;

    print('Key: $key, Value: $value');
    // Key: a, Value: 1
    // Key: b, Value: 2
    // Key: c, Value: 3
    // Key: d, Value: 4
    // Key: e, Value: 5
  }
}
```

You can also rather easy introduce your own `Pair` class which allows you to bind two objects together:

```
class Pair<T1, T2> {
  final T1 a;
  final T2 b;

  Pair(this.a, this.b);
}

void main() {
  final testList = [
    Pair("a", 1),
    Pair("b", 2),
    Pair("c", 3),
    Pair("d", 4),
    Pair("e", 5)
  ];

  for (final pair in testList) {
    print('${pair.a} -> ${pair.b}');
  }
  // a -> 1
  // b -> 2
  // c -> 3
  // d -> 4
  // e -> 5
}
```

In most cases I will recommend you to make a `class` for you specific need since it makes it easier to make type safe code.

Comment: There's already `MapEntry`, which is essentially the same as `Pair` above.

Comment: @wu-lee Yes, but just because we have a class which have a similar behavior, it is not a reason to use it for an purpose it is not intended for (the documentation for `MapEntry` says: "A key/value pair representing an entry in a `Map`."). It would be very weird to use `MapEntry` around your code every time you want to have a method returning two values. But should be noted I am already using `MapEntry` in my first example implicit since that is what we get from `testMap.entries`. But that does also makes sense since I am using a `Map` here.

Answer (score 17):

Dart 3 came out in May 2023, and includes a new feature called `Records`.

In most languages, a tuple has usually only positional fields, and a record has named fields. Dart combines these two. A `Record` in dart can have both positional and named fields.

When you create a `Record` with only positional fields, it's just a tuple:

```dart
var tuple = ("first", 2, true);
```

You can use it as return type for example:

```
(int, String) foo() {
    return (1, "string");
}
```

It can be deconstructed like this:

```
var (a, b) = foo();
```

So your example code in Dart 3 would look something like this:

```
List testList = [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3),("d",4),("e",5)];
  
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var (stringVal, intVal) = testList[i];
  print('hello ${stringVal} ${intVal}');
}
```

This is the specification:

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/3.0/records/feature-specification.md

Answer (score 9):

There is no built-in tuple type in Dart 2, so if you want them, you'll need to explicitly construct tuple types and then explicitly access their members, as with any other class. (In other words, there is no automatic structuring or destructuring.)

Using [`package:tuple`](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple), you could do:

```dart
void main() {
  var testList = <Tuple2<String, int>>[
    Tuple2("a", 1),
    Tuple2("b", 2),
    Tuple2("c", 3),
    Tuple2("d", 4),
    Tuple2("e", 5),
  ];
  
  for (var tuple in testList) {
    print('current tuple: (${tuple.item1}, ${tuple.item2})');
  }
}
```