# How to create a simple Tuple class in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why I cannot initialize this class?

```
class ChangeThis<T1, T2> {
  final T1 item1;
  final T2 item2;

  ChangeThis({
    this.item1,
    this.item2,
  });
}

int main() {
  ChangeThis<bool, int> changeThis = new ChangeThis<bool, int>(true, 0);
}
```

I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060545, but I get:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
  ChangeThis<bool, int> changeThis = new ChangeThis<bool, int>(true, 0);
```

Comment: Curly braces (`{}`) in a parameter list indicate *named* arguments.  If you want optional, *positional* arguments, use square brackets (`[]`).  Or if you don't want optional arguments, don't put any extra brackets or braces around the parameters.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ChangeThis<bool, int> changeThis = new ChangeThis<bool, int>(item1: true, item2: 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is you are not using positional arguments. I recommend going through the Dart tour, specifically the [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) part. By using the `{}` inside your constructor you are creating named constructors. Thus you would need the constructor to look like the following:
`ChangeThis<bool, int> changeThis = new ChangeThis<bool, int>(item1: true, item2: 0);`

If you wanted to have positional arguments in your constructor, then you could just remove the `{}` in your constructor to look like this:

```
 ChangeThis(
    T1 item1,
    T2 item2
  ) {
  this.item1 = item1;
  this.item2 = item2;
}
```

However as you see the named constructor is a nice shortcut that Dart includes.